# Am I missing the lualatex format source?

Tags: miktex, luatex, installing

I am trying to get lualatex to run on my MikTeX 2.9 installation.
When I attempt to create the format, I get the following error message (via mo.exe):

`Creating the lualatex format file...
miktex-makefmt: The application file "" could not be found.
initexmf.EXE: The operation failed for some reason.
initexmf.EXE: Data: H:\MikTex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\bin\miktex-makefmt.exe`

Does anyone know what or where the "application file" is or should be that causes the miktex-makefmt complaint?

Comment: Isn't the format created on installation? Did you try to create it with MiKTeX Options?

Comment: I didn't originally install luatex/lualatex. So I used mo to install the binaries and packages. This put three copies of lualatex.ini in various places in the texmf hierarchy. I still get the error message after updating the search-database. It appears that miktex-makefmt expects a filename. Does initexmf assemble a command line? And how? Which configuration file must I update?

Comment: Probably, you should make the formats with `MiKTeX Options`, `Formats` tab. Ther, select the `lualatex` line, click on the `Change` button to edit the configuration. You should have: Format key/name `lualatex`, Compiler: `luatex`, Input file name: `lualatex.ini`, Description: `LuaLaTeX`. Click on OK, then on `Build`.

Comment: Check the format definition in miktex settings. Perhaps it is defect, it sounds as if there is no input file declared.

Comment: formats.ini in "texmf\miktex\config" contains section and key values (I can't get the miniformats to work write here - how do I put in linefeeds?), `[lualatex]
input=lualatex.ini
description=LuaLaTeX
compiler=luatex
attributes=

[luatex]
input=luatex.ini
description=LuaTeX
compiler=luatex
attributes=
`          - to my mind the files have been defined here. Do they Need to be defined elsewhere?

Comment: Check the settings in miktex settings. There can be other formats.ini somewhere. So it is important to check what is actually used.

Comment: Well, I checked MikTeX Options (mo.exe) and am curious if that's where I Need to check. When I view the Options (via Change) it tell me that the luatex Compiler cannot be found. What Compiler is used for luatex? I notice pdftex is used to compile the pdftex Format. Isn't luatex then used to compile the luatex Format? A lualatex.exe exists, but no luatex.exe? However I notice there's a luatexdef.exe and a lualatexdef.exe. Am I missing a binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on a Network that gets "supported" by IT Folks. The IT Folks silently(secretly) installed a Version of miktex 2.9 on the computer I use, changed paths, Environment variables etc. and neglected to inform me of their support.

So my problem and solution are for people who work on Networks with support from an IT department : *always* verify your Paths, Environment variables, Registry settings etc.etc.

Also, it took two or three times for mo.exe (and friends) to install the luatex binaries in their proper place. But this was probably caused by the conflicts generated by my "Support" Situation.

Sorry to have wasted anyone's time.